Migrate Pentaho Models / Tables to PostgrestDB
I'm having some problems with pentaho - data-integration - kettle
api.sh:
#!/bin/bash

# ------------------------------------------------- EJERCICIO Y TRIMESTRE ------------------------------------------------- #
# Definir valores predeterminados
EJERCICIO=""
TRIMESTRE=""
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="2134"  
echo "Configuración de conexión a la base de datos:"
echo "Host: $POSTGRES_HOST"
echo "Puerto: $POSTGRES_PORT"
echo "Nombre de la base de datos: $POSTGRES_NAME"
echo "Usuario: $POSTGRES_USER"
echo "Contraseña: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD"  # Cuidado al imprimir contraseñas


# Procesar los argumentos del script
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    key="$1"

    case $key in
        --ejercicio)
            EJERCICIO="$2"
            shift
            ;;
        --trimestre)
            TRIMESTRE="$2"
            shift
            ;;
        *)
            # Argumento desconocido o mal formado
            echo "Argumento desconocido: $1"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

# Verificar si se proporcionaron los parámetros requeridos
if [ -z "$EJERCICIO" ] || [ -z "$TRIMESTRE" ]; then
    echo "Error: Falta uno o más parámetros requeridos."
    echo "Uso: ./eph_descaga_csv.sh --ejercicio EJERCICIO --trimestre TRIMESTRE"
    exit 1
fi

# ------------------------------------------------- KETTLE CONFIGURATION ------------------------------------------------- #

# Setear el path al ejecutable de kitchen
[ -z "$KITCHEN" ] && export KITCHEN="/opt/pentaho/data-integration/kitchen.sh"
# Setear el path al directorio de ETL
[ -z "$ETL_PATH" ] && export ETL_PATH="/opt/tdf/datalaketdf/etl/eph/kettle"
ETL_FILE="$ETL_PATH/JobEPHDescargaCSV.kjb"

# Setear log level
[ -z "$LOG_LEVEL" ] && export LOG_LEVEL="Basico"
#(Basico, Detallado, Debug, NivelFila, Error, Nada)

# jdbc.properties
export JNDI_DIR="$ETL_PATH/jndi/"

if [ ! -d "$JNDI_DIR" ]; then
    mkdir "$JNDI_DIR"
fi

fileName="$JNDI_DIR/jdbc.properties"
# Recreate  file
rm "$fileName"
touch "$fileName"

# Write properties to file
echo "$KETTLE_DB_NAME/type=javax.sql.DataSource" > $fileName
echo "$KETTLE_DB_NAME/driver=org.postgresql.Driver" >> $fileName
echo "$KETTLE_DB_NAME/url=jdbc:postgresql://$POSTGRES_HOST:$POSTGRES_PORT/$POSTGRES_NAME" >> $fileName
echo "$KETTLE_DB_NAME/user=$POSTGRES_USER" >> $fileName
echo "$KETTLE_DB_NAME/password=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" >> $fileName

# ---------------------------------------------------- KETTLE RUN ------------------------------------------------------- #
KETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=$JNDI_DIR $KITCHEN -file=$ETL_FILE -level=$LOG_LEVEL -param:EJERCICIO=$EJERCICIO -param:TRIMESTRE=$TRIMESTRE

this sh is one of we use to communicate an py api with ketter and ketter with postgestdb
All works fine, but, the problem is Ketter first asked me a DB that doesn't exist.
Ok... I created with a sql.init.
And now ask me this >
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Unexpected batch update error committing the database connection.
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseBatchException:
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 - Error updating batch
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 - Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "public".logs_etl (etl_name, "state", step) VALUES ( 'Descarga CSV Indec',  'Inicio',  'Iniciando descarga de CSV') was aborted: ERROR: relation "public.logs_etl" does not exist
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -   Position: 13  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.createKettleDatabaseBatchException(Database.java:1440)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.emptyAndCommit(Database.java:1429)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.dispose(TableOutput.java:590)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:97)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 - Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "public".logs_etl (etl_name, "state", step) VALUES ( 'Descarga CSV Indec',  'Inicio',  'Iniciando descarga de CSV') was aborted: ERROR: relation "public.logs_etl" does not exist
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -   Position: 13  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:169)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.postgresql.core.ResultHandlerDelegate.handleError(ResultHandlerDelegate.java:52)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:520)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.internalExecuteBatch(PgStatement.java:878)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:901)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeBatch(PgPreparedStatement.java:1644)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.emptyAndCommit(Database.java:1416)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    ... 3 more
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 - Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "public.logs_etl" does not exist
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -   Position: 13
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2552)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - Insert Log.0 -    ... 8 more
2024/10/04 16:41:30 - InitLogDescarcarCSVIndec - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2024/10/04 16:41:31 - InitLogDescarcarCSVIndec - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2024/10/04 16:41:31 - Kitchen - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Finished with errors

I don't know how migrate or do something equal like makemigrations and migrate like Python/ Django
